# Existe algum Interpretador para C?

Tags: c, interpretador

Gostaria de testar pequenos trechos de código em C da mesma forma que posso fazer com Python, abrindo o terminal e testando comando por comando, isso seria possível com c?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já testei o cling. Recomendo por ser baseado no clang, que é mais inteligente em diagnóstico, capaz de oferecer mensagens de erros mais simples que um baseado em gcc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem vários você pode usar o próprio [GDB como shell interativo](http://blog.pclewis.com/2010/03/tip-using-gdb-as-an-interactive-c-shell/), outro debug que pode ser usado como shell interativo é o [UPS](http://ups.sourceforge.net/).

Além do [Picoc](https://code.google.com/p/picoc/downloads/detail?name=picoc-2.1.tar.bz2) já citado por você também posso citar

- [ccons](https://code.google.com/p/ccons/)
- [o c-repl](http://neugierig.org/software/c-repl/)
- [Ch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch_%28computer_programming%29)
- [CINT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CINT)
- [cling](https://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cling)

Answer (score 2):

Encontrei o **[Picoc](https://code.google.com/p/picoc/downloads/detail?name=picoc-2.1.tar.bz2)**

1. Clique no link e baixe os arquivos de instalação
2. Abra em uma pasta e digite no terminal  make | make test
3. Execute Picoc passando parâmetro -i, assim  ./picoc  -i

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
você pode executar vários programas de forma interativa

```
 picoc myprog1.c myprog2.c myprog3.c
```

Se você gosta de programar com vim usando Tmux ou algo do gênero, você pode desenvolver seu programa em uma janela e ver o resultado em outro em "tempo real"